# How to set Chrome's user script version number

Tags: google-chrome, version, greasemonkey, userscripts

**Edit**: The bug that caused this problem has been fixed. The `@version` tag now works in the stable release. See [Issue 30760](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30760)

---

Hey.

I've been wondering how I might set the version number displayed for user-scripts in Chrome's extension tab

[image: Example image]
<sub>(source: [advefir.com](http://atli.advefir.com/images/chrome_user-script_version.jpeg))</sub>

So far the obvious methods have failed:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @version 1.1.5
// @uso:version 1.1.5
// ==/UserScript==
```

I know Greasemonkey for Firefox doesn't use a version value, but since Chrome actually displays a version number, I thought it might.

Perhaps this is a feature that has not been implemented?
Or maybe it was never intended to be there, but it is there because extensions have version numbers, and user-scripts are currently installed as extensions?

*(I'm using the Linux beta, version: 4.0.249.43, by the way)*

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this appears to be a confirmed bug now. ([Issue 30760](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30760))

Seems the standard `@version` meta-data is the correct usage, <strike>but it has not yet been implemented.</strike>

**Edit**: The `@version` tag now works in the stable release of Chromium (and, therefore, Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

> Or maybe it was never intended to be there, but it is there because extensions have version numbers, and user-scripts are currently installed as extensions?

I think so.

Version number used for updating extensions. User scripts currently can not update. "Update extensions now" button doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, but apparently not yet released:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30760#c16